# MVC Redirect from view to action using Razor without clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I'm trying to Redirect from view to action using Razor without clicking.
Sometimes an error occurs when the page is loading.

I made a try and catch block to redirect.

View:

```
@{
    var x = Session["Username"];

    try
    {
        if (x.ToString().Equals(item.User.UserName))
        {
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("تعديل", "Edit", new { id = item.NotificationID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("التفاصيل", "Details", new { id = item.NotificationID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("حذف", "Delete", new { id = item.NotificationID })    
            </td>
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        //I want to redirect to an action, not view.
    }
}
```

Edit:

Home Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[AuthorizeUserAccessLevel(UserRole = "Manager,Reviewer")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    TheUnitOfEnternalAuditEntities db = new TheUnitOfEnternalAuditEntities();



    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        username = username.Replace("NCA\\", "");

        User user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(username)).First();





        Session["UserName"] = username;
        Session["UserID"] = user.UserID;
        Session["UserFirstName"] = user.FirstName;
        Session["UserFullName"] = user.FullName;
        Session["UserRole"] = user.Role.RoleID;


        var Departments = db.Departments.ToList();

        ViewBag.Departments = Departments;


        return View(db.Departments.ToList());
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I think it will be better if you understand why the catch should happen, and redirect in controller not in view...

Comment: Your `if` block belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan   the problem happen when the user go to some pages without passing throw home controller, i stored multiple sessions in index action of home controller. some users put action name in address bar before go to home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to redirect to an error page, then just enable the CustomError mode in web.config file.

But in your case you're trying to redirect to the index action, which could be a listing of items in your application.

What's the use of doing this through a view? A view isn't meant for writing a business logic, it should be only used as a view template.

Comment: The purpose of redirection is filling the sessions before go to any actions. Some users put action name in address bar before go to home controller. i edited the Question.